# How can I remove a gem from my Rails 3 project without getting this really strange Bundle error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, bundle, bundler

The error is:
You have modified your Gemfile in development but did not check
the resulting snapshot (Gemfile.lock) into version control

WHAT VERSION CONTROL? Why/how does Bundle know anything about version control?  I just removed a line from my Gemfile. Am I not supposed to do that?

Comment: Never seen this before. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Did you run `bundle update` after you changed your `Gemfile`? Can you please post the output from that, and any output details related to the error message?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do `rm -rf .bundle && bundle install` from your project root.

Comment: geez, Rails starts to get control freak!